# JS : Compatibility problem with Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, cross-browser

I have a small portion of code which works well on FF but I can't seem to get it to work on Safari unless I put an alert instruction anywhere inside of the whiles.

Anyone knows what may be the problem ?

```
    var liste_ele = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion_content');
    i=0;
    while(i<liste_ele.length)
    {
        var j=0;
        var liste_sel = liste_ele[i].getElementsByTagName('select');
        while(j<liste_sel.length)
        {
            liste_sel[j].style.visibility = '';
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Define in what way it "doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: Well I have different <select> that are hidden when I load my page and I made this little script to make them visible again.
I tested it on FF and it just went fine, but for unknown reasons, it won't work on safari unless I input an alert instruction in my whiles...

Comment: Probably not relevant, but you're defining `i` as a global variable - are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: I had already defined i a few lines ago, I'm just reinitializing it to 0 for the while to follow.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try setting `visibility` to `visible` instead of `''`.

```
liste_sel[j].style.visibility = 'visible';
```

And are they really hidden by setting `visibility` to `hidden` or are the hidden by `display:none` that might also make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If putting an alert in your while loop solves the problem, it's almost certainly a timing issue. Where in the DOM is this code being run? Are you sure it's being run AFTER the elements you're trying to find are created?

A simple test would be to put your code inside a timeout:

```
  window.setTimeout(function(){   
    // your code here 
  },100);
```

If that works, then your issue is related to order of operations; make sure your DOM is created before attempting to access it.

Answer (score 0):

@jitter : I already tried to set visibility to visible, but I didn't have a result so I just tried '', hoping it would help. And yes, my elements are hidden and not undisplayed, otherwise my script wouldn't run perfect on FF.

@jvenema : This looks like a good solution indeed :)

Even though I don't know why would my elements not be created since they are initialised as visibility:hidden by another script in my firmware before I pass on them with this script :/

Anyway thanks, you just solved my problem (well I had solved it the good way, by modifying the script that sets it to hidden but I was curious :p) ! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to block off the position then use the style display:none. Otherwise hide it initially as Safari will render the page initially with the style visibility:hidden you just won't be able to toggle it with Javascript. As a workaround just toggle the opacity with the javascript;

```
document.getElementById('Div').style.opacity = 0; to make it disappear
```

and

```
document.getElementById('Div').style.opacity = 100; to make it reappear.
```

Its holding up for me until Safari gets it together.